# features.h not found solus linux, what is it and how do I get it?

Tags: c++, linux, compiler-errors

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5.3.0/x86_64-solus-linux/bits/c++config.h:482:0,
             from /usr/include/c++/5.3.0/cstdlib:41,
             from prog1.h:4,
             from prog1.cc:1:
/usr/include/c++/5.3.0/x86_64-solus-linux/bits/os_defines.h:39:22: fatal error: features.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

I'm fairly new to Linux/Unix and I'm trying just get basic c++ compiling on Solus (running on a virtual machine). I've installed gcc and g++ and as far as I can tell the standard c++ libraries are installed.

However, I am getting the error message shown above when I try to compile a program. This is my header file:

```
#ifndef PROG1_H
#define PROG1_H

#include<cstdlib>
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
#include<vector>


const int VEC_SIZE = 250;
const int LOW = 1;
const int HIGH = 10000;
const int ITEMS_PER_LINE = 12;
const int ITEM_W = 5;
const int SEED = 1;

void genRndNums(vector<int>& v); // generates random integers and assigns them to the vector array

void printVec(const vector<int>& v); // prints the vector array, 12 numbers per line

#endif
```

for some reason the file features.h is missing and I don't know what it is or how to get it. If anybody can help with this I would really appreciate it.

Comment: It looks like others have experienced this... https://solus-project.com/forums/viewtopic.php?t=591

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Please install the `system.devel` component. Installing a compiler alone is not sufficient, you need headers and libraries too.

```
sudo eopkg it -c system.devel
```

Think of it as our equivalent to `build-essential`

Comment: Guys on IRC asked me to mention you need to ensure your system is fully up to date before installing components :)

`sudo eopkg up`